# MySQL Транспонировать и перестроить таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующая таблица:

| ts | choice_one | choice_two | correct_one | correct_two |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | ok | ok | ok | crit |
| 222 | ok | ok | ok | ok |

Нужен запрос SQL, который создает на ее основе следующую:

| ts | category | choice | correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | one | ok | ok |
| 111 | two | ok | crit |
| 222 | one | ok | ok |
| 222 | two | ok | ok |

**Пояснения по происходящему**

Должны появиться колонки choice и correct (были частью заголовков), а one и two (вторая часть заголовков) отделяются в новую колонку category. На пересечении их собственно остаются соответствующие значения.

В рабочей таблице порядка 20 категорий one, two, three и т.д. (их названия заранее известны), для каждой из которых существует пара choice - correct (фактическая и верная разметка категорий соответственно), итого около 40 колонок. Нужно сделать таким образом "разворачивание" таблицы по вертикали, когда останется только 4 вышеописанные колонки, но число строк увеличится.

Comment: UNION ALL в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

С подсказкой Akina получил решение.
Используем UNION ALL, либо в моем случае UNION (дает эффект UNION ALL + DISTINCT)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  ts INT,
  choice_one varchar(50),
  choice_two varchar(50),
  etalon_one varchar(50),
  etalon_two varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO mytable (ts, choice_one, choice_two, etalon_one, etalon_two) VALUES
('111', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'crit'),
('222', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok');

SELECT ts, choice_one AS choice, 'one' AS category
FROM mytable
  UNION
SELECT ts, choice_two AS choice, 'two' AS category
FROM mytable
  UNION
SELECT ts, etalon_one AS correct, 'one' AS category
FROM mytable
  UNION
SELECT ts, etalon_two AS correct, 'two' AS category
FROM mytable
```

В зависимости от версии может сложить choise и correct в одну колонку. В моем случае разложило в две, как и нужно.